# why rook cephfs storage class store pv data in 2 places?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, ceph, cephfs, rook

I am a newbie to ceph and run ceph using rook in bare metal environment.my question is :
when you use rook cephfs provisioner as storage class and create a pvc to assign to a pod , when the pv is craeted , there are two dir that store the contents of pv:

1. **/var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/csi/rook-ceph.cephfs.csi.ceph.com/23e9856c1857315467f4b40369f3c54dbb553fa69a7f52fb4f98b256cdb3c709/globalmount**

   2.**/var/lib/kubelet/pods/e9e8fb85-8557-455c-8ea8-4d4bf95ebd62/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-2e990ca3-0640-49d7-aea6-ce0400c83bef/mount**

what is the reason and logic behind this ?

Comment: According to [this doc](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/deploying.html) the /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/ is the "socket-dir": # This volume is where the socket for kubelet->driver communication is done. And /var/lib/kubelet/pods is the mountpoint-dir: # This volume is where the driver mounts volumes.